# Review audit of deleted answer shows personal information

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, privacy, email-addresses

I just received a review audit. It used a deleted answer, but the answer contains personal information about that user including their phone number and email address. Here's the text with the personal information removed:

> Hi my name is Ashley reading and I'm hoping that you can possibly help me. I feel like that my phone has been hacked and I don't know what to do, I'm not smart with some I don't sit around and try to steal people's information all day like some people that I have obviously met that I tested and they've got my information and I don't know how to get it off of there I'm hoping that you can possibly help me it would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry for bothering you with this again I'm hoping that you can help me my direct phone number is [REDACTED] and my email is [REDACTED]@gmail.com. anything that you could possibly do to leave me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate thank you for taking the time to read my email I'm sorry my forearm and I appreciate it greatly thanks again I hope to hear from you soon thank you very much and have a great holiday
>
> answered Dec 11 at 2:16
>
> user14804936

I don't think that deleted answers that contain personal information should be "undeleted" and shown to reviewers, unless this was just placeholder personal information as part of a test.

Comment: This isn't a bug. The system can't know if the deleted content is confidential. Content isn't actually removed when deleted. Any user who can see deleted posts will be able to see it. As you've seen, the post may also be used in an audit. If something is confidential (e.g. PII, login credentials, etc.) and was posted by mistake, then edit those parts out and raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request that the information be redacted. While editing it out isn't absolutely required, it makes handling such flags *much* easier, as it shows *exactly* what you're concerned about.

Comment: I'm not able to see deleted posts - what's the best way to flag this audit for personal information? I would definitely love to get it handled the right way and redacted, but when I visit the post the answer isn't there.

Comment: As with any time you can't flag the thing you think needs moderator attention, pick a post, any post (usually one of your own, another post by the same author, or if what you want to flag about is a answer, then, perhaps, the question it's on). Then, raise a flag on the post that you picked. Be explicit and specific that you're flagging about some other post. Say that first, along with a link to the thing you're flagging about. After that, describe the issue you're wanting to bring to the moderators' attention.

Comment: Note that posts of this type are almost certainly phishing attempts, trying to attract someone willing to help a maiden in distress. We see these exact same type of posts with some regularity on Stack Overflow. I wouldn’t worry too much about the PII here. Still, I’ll see if I can remove this post from being used for audits.

Comment: And having reviewed a few more examples, I am reasonably sure these fit in with other more direct spam advertising a phone hacking goon-for-hire. At any rate, they specific post is no longer going to be used for audits.